# VB.NET How to enter text into a website textbox without a "value" attribute

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am making a program that finds the source URL of a video from the website, www.clicktoview.org. I can download the captcha it requires, and display it, but I can't solve it with the user's input because the text box on the website doesn't have a `value=""` attribute.

Here is the relevant part of the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field">
```

With this hindrance, is there any way I can input the user's captcha interpretation to the text field?

My code would be

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("recaptcha_response_field").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
```

but there isn't a `value` attribute.

N.B. The website is http://clicktoview.org/jbs2xyb89uai

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with your code.

> WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("recaptcha_response_field").SetAttribute("value",
>   TextBox2.Text)

should do what you want.
Even if a htmlElement doens't have a written value="" field you could still set it.

Have you checked to see that the **GetElementById("recaptcha_response_field")** returns a valid htmlElement?

```
            Dim htmlElement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("recaptcha_response_field")
            If htmlElement IsNot Nothing Then
                htmlElement.SetAttribute("value",TextBox2.Text)
            End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it seems it doesn't return a valid htmlElement. I don't understand why it doesn't, because it clearly exists. I tried using HTMLAgilityPack, but it returned the same error. Could it be because I'm clicking on a button before-hand, which loads a new page with the same URL? Any help appreaciated!

Comment: I can't help you with that, my malwarebytes anti-malware blocks the clicktoview.org website